# AFNetworking 2 NSURLErrorDomain

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

I am trying to use AFNetworking 2, and I fail.

Following the recommendations, I did the following:

```
#import "AFHTTPSessionManager.h"
@interface OperationManager : AFHTTPRequestOperationManager

+ (instancetype)sharedClient;

@end


@implementation OperationManager

+ (instancetype)sharedClient {
    static OperationManager *_sharedClient = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedClient = [[OperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kBaseURL]];
        [_sharedClient setSecurityPolicy:[AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModePublicKey]];
    });

    return _sharedClient;
}

@end
```

And here is how I am trying to use it:

```
    OperationManager * manager = [OperationManager sharedClient];
    NSString * link = kAuth;

//    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager* manager =[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
//    NSString * link = [kBaseURL stringByAppendingString:kAuth];

    [manager GET:link parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

the constants are used from example project:

```
static NSString * const kBaseURL = @"https://alpha-api.app.net/";
static NSString * const  kAuth = @"stream/0/posts/stream/global";
```

When i run this code, here is what I get:

> Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)"
>   UserInfo=0x15d97e50
>   {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://alpha-api.app.net/stream/0/posts/stream/global,
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://alpha-api.app.net/stream/0/posts/stream/global}

If I comment the 2 lines with OperationManager and it's link, and uncomment the `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` with it's link, everything works.

I am debugging and digging for a answer since yesterday's morning.

Comment: What is the link set to when you do a NSLog of it? I'd like to see the value of NSString *link = kAuth

Comment: sure, its /stream/0/posts/stream/global.
when i enter inside the GET:param:succ:fail method, we can see the final URL is correct - https://alpha-api.app.net/stream/0/posts/stream/global, because via singleton initiator i assign the baseURL, so it does exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, the AFHTTPRequestOperationManager has a default AFSecurityPolicy of AFSSLPinningModeNone.

That appears to me to be the only difference between the two calls.